# magento new order send mail not work

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.9

magento can send new user mail confirmation, newsletter subscription, invoice and shipment success but can't send new order mail and send order email to customer in admin panel.

in database core_email_queue is full of not sent emails

also i did:

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

and add:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/salar/public_html/cron.sh
```

this is my AOE Scheduler:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiYcw.png

Answer (score 0):

As of magento 1.9, emails are queued up and are sent via the cron job. If you haven't set this up, you can manually run it by pointing your browser to the file, e.g. http://www.yoursite/cron.php . After you run this, you should receive your emails

The extension AOE_Scheduler can help you in confirming that your Magento cronjob has been configured correctly and is running.

Comment: What should be the correct cron configuration in backend

Comment: go to your cpanel or local configured cron job */5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh